# Viewing images with relative path through Attributes Form in QGIS

Tags: qgis, image, path

I work with [Sw maps](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=np.com.softwel.swmaps&hl=it) (field data collector) that generates shapefiles in which a field  links to images through relative path. Originally I had non problem using Evis plugin, now discontinued.
Now I try using widgets in Attributes Form.

This is the path where the shapefile is stored: `D:\DOCUMENTI\RELAZIONI\sovralluvionamento\shape e vettoriali\New layers sovralluvio\Layers 2020\lanche Shapefiles`

This is the Relative path in the field `_Foto`: `\Photos\lanche_20201005_153029157.jpg`

I open layer Properties and work in Attributes Form making the steps below, but when I try to view images by Identify Features does not work:

[image: Attributes_Form_1]

[image: Attributes_Form_2]